# CSS3 transition abort causes ugly animation

Tags: css

I'm using a CSS3 step transition to animate a sprite from one state to another.

When I start one animation it shows the frames one at a time and has a nice transition effect (click "show/hide" link in the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lc31fjt6/15/)). But when a second transition is triggered while the first one is still running the frame position get's lost and it looks like it scrolls to the other side instead of maintaining the frame-by-frame animation (click "trigger bug" in the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lc31fjt6/15/)).

```
.tree {
    width: 26px; /* one frame */
    height: 31px; /* frame height */
    background-image: url("http://rolandschuetz.at/docs/tree-animated.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -234px 0; /* last frame */
    transition: background-position .8s steps(10); /* this triggers the CSS3 step transition */
}
.tree-hidden {
    background-position: 26px 0; /* clear, before first frame */
}
```

Is there a way to force the animation to work correctly even when it aborted an older one?

PS: Please not try to "fix" by trigger-bug button which is only there for demo purposes. The real problem is triggered by fast user interaction which should have immediate feedback.

Comment: Did you press the "trigger bug" link? If so, in which browser?

Comment: yea did but since its your animation you have to explain whats ugly there so that i can find ugly part

Comment: when i press tree size gets reduced to small and scroll from left to right

Comment: Yes, and it shouldn't scroll. This should be a frame-by-frame grow animation like you can see when you press the show/hide link.

Comment: I've figured out what's going on here, I'll draw up a diagram and put it an answer below.

Comment: @RolandSchütz its because of time `}, 300)`

Comment: I know what's going on. The problem is that the "show/hide" button should work nicely even when the user clicks it twice with less then 0.5sec between. So your proposal doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: You could't solve it without using javascript to detect transaction events starts and end.

Comment: @RolandSchütz No, when I double clicked `show/hide` button, the output was similar to clicking `trigger bug`.

Answer (score 2):

[Updated code](http://jsfiddle.net/Lc31fjt6/18/)

Check if this helps you.

HTML

```
<div class="outer"> <!--Added this div-->
  <div class="tree"></div>        
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
    width: 26px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
.tree {
    width: 26px; /* one frame */
    height: 31px;

    background-image: url("http://rolandschuetz.at/docs/tree-animated.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -234px 0; /* last frame */
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    margin: 0 auto;    
    /*Changed transition*/
    -webkit-transition: all .8s;
       -moz-transition: all .8s;
        -ms-transition: all .8s;
            transition: all .8s;
}
.tree-hidden {
    /* background-position: 26px 0; */ /* empty, before first frame */
    width: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
}
```

Comment: That's a nice idea, but it doesn't look as good as the frame-by-frame animation.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the issue:

There are 10 frames, hence you use 10 steps for the animation.
So basically, the CSS is stepping the tree 10 times for tree-active and 10 times for tree-not-active.

If you de-activate the tree at frame 8, it will reverse the animation direction as expected but it will step 10 times instead of 8. This makes it look like it is sliding but it's actually just stopping in the 10 interval positions for the 8 frames.

Does this make sense?

For this type of animation you'd be better off using a JS solution where it knows the current frame position and calculates the steps needed correctly.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. It would be really cool if there would be a CSS-only solution.

Comment: @RolandSchütz Unfortunately, I don't think so. I could do up a quick fiddle with minimal JS but I think JS is the way to go here. CSS doesn't store data so it couldn't know the current position (which you'd need to re-calculate the steps needed).

Comment: Since I'm running about 70 of those each with different transition-durations a not hardware accelerated version will likely cause performance issues.

Comment: A not optimal bug way better solution would be if the interrupting animation would start from the finish point of the last transition. So the tree would suddenly change it size, but there would be no strange scrolling effect.

Comment: @RolandSchütz So, like this? http://jsfiddle.net/pavkr/Lc31fjt6/19/ I just gave it alternate transition times.

Comment: In this case you broke the whole hide-animation. I'm thinking about maybe keeping state of if I'm in a transition via js and if so then I set the transition time to 0 for the next transition. Thanks.

Comment: @RolandSchütz, that fiddle above hides the tree (animated) and then when you stop and start the animation mid-animation it will jump to the large tree "So the tree would suddenly change it size", looks like this is what you're explaining for the JS as well. Apologies if I have misunderstood.

Answer (score 2):

As ThePav says, there is no way to make CSS know in wich state it is. So, it will aplly always a steps(10) function, even when starting from the middle of the previous transition, and with a background-position that would need less steps.

The easiest way to solve this (not easy, but the easiest) is to set a parallel z-index transition, set the same way as the background-position. If you can give them any z-index, then the z-index would go from 0 to 10.

```
.tree {
    background-position: -234px 0; 
    z-index: 0;
    transition: all .8s steps(10); // will apply both to bkg-position and z-index
}
.tree-hidden {
    background-position: 26px 0; 
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Then, the z-index property serves as an indicator of a ongoing transition,and you can set the steps function accordingly, in the scripting to change the class.

That is, get value of z-index, and set that to transitionTimingFunction: 'steps (' + zindexval + ')'

(You could do this also with the background-position property, but it is way harder.)

The code would be

```
function change () {
    var tree = $('.tree').eq(0);
    if (tree.hasClass('tree-hidden')) {
        var where = tree.css("zIndex");
        if (where != 10) {
            tree.css({transitionTimingFunction: 'steps(' + where + ')'})
        } else {
            tree.css({transitionTimingFunction: ''})
        }
        tree.removeClass('tree-hidden');
    } else {
        tree.css({transitionTimingFunction: ''})
        tree.addClass('tree-hidden');
    }

}
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lc31fjt6/22/)

Comment: What do you mean with parallel z-index transition? Thanks :)

Comment: Added more detail :-)

Comment: Thanks for all the work. Sadly that doesn't work in my browser. I think I will find a different solution anyway, because the code just get's too bloated. I will simply keep a timer in js.

Comment: Ok, don't worry. Good luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use transitionend for waiting to remove 'tree-hidden' class. Else you could't solve by another way.

```
$('.show-hide').click(function() {
    !$('.tree').hasClass('tree-hidden') &&
    $('.tree').addClass('tree-hidden').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(e) {
        $('.tree').removeClass('tree-hidden')
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

```
 $('.show-hide').click(function(evt) {
    //JUST CHECK ALREADY HAS HIDDEN CLASS
    if($('.tree').hasClass('tree-hidden'))
     //you can event prevent defaul if there is no another work
     evt.preventDefault();
     return false;
    $('.tree').addClass('tree-hidden').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(e) {
        $('.tree').removeClass('tree-hidden')
    });
});
```

By this way, transaction would not break until animation done, regardless of clicking more time.

**css transaction fallback**

If you need fallback you can use code below

```
function supportsTransitions() {
   var b = document.body || document.documentElement,
    s = b.style,
    p = 'transition';

    if (typeof s[p] == 'string') { return true; }

    // Tests for vendor specific prop
    var v = ['Moz', 'webkit', 'Webkit', 'Khtml', 'O', 'ms'];
    p = p.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + p.substr(1);

    for (var i=0; i<v.length; i++) {
        if (typeof s[v[i] + p] == 'string') { return true; }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: That does not give the user immediate feedback and might confuse him. So he clicks three times and then there a lot of useless animation.

Comment: Just check if transaction still going on, I have updated for you